# How to remove '.0', or the decimal point from string values in a column that also contains values that are text?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Consider the following dataframe:

| Store Number | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 121 |
| 2.0 | 85 |
| 3.0 | 32 |
| ABC | 89 |
| BCD | 94 |
| CDE | 4 |

I want to remove the '.0' from the store number. The dtype is string. I want the output to look like this:

| Store Number | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 |
| 2 | 85 |
| 3 | 32 |
| ABC | 89 |
| BCD | 94 |
| CDE | 4 |

I have tried:
df = df['Store Number'].replace('.0','')

as well as:
df = df['Store Number'].replace('.\d0','')

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
x = df['Store Number'].split('.')[0]
```

This will allow you to access the number to the left of the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

The final code that worked for me was:

```
df['Store Number'] = df['Store Number'].str.replace(r"\.0",'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as:

```
df['Store Number'] = df['Store Number'].str.replace('.0','')
```

print(df)

Output

```
  Store Number Count
0            1   121
1            2    85
2            3    32
3          ABC    89
4          BCD    94
5          CDE     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a testable alternative that broadens regex matching a bit.

- No digit after decimal point
- Single or many digits/characters after decimal point
- Blank spaces after decimal point

```python
    # Sample data
    d = { 'A': '1.0', 'B': '2.02333', 'C': '3.011333axxd', 'D': 'ABC', 'E': '1.', 'F': 'CDE' }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame([d])
    df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].str.replace('(\.).*', '', regex=True)
    print(df)
```

This example is performing replacement over the entire column at index zero. It's worth mentioning that this solution doesn't perform inline type casting, as the sample values are all strings.